# Unit Testing in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I am using Android Studio 1.2

Say I have a simple method add in some class MyAdder

```
public int add(int a,int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

I want to perform the unit test and use assertions to perform the test for the above-mentioned code.

I found it tough, to begin with, Testing Fundamentals from the official DEV site so a sample code or a detailed tutorial for performing unit tests would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @2Dee I believe this is on topic ? isn't it ? please let me know why if it isn't so that I can learn thank you sir

Comment: Point 4 on that page states that questions asking to recommend tools or tutorials is off-topic on SO. It is because opinionated or link-only answers are more likely than a proper how-to for this type of question. Consider this : if we had to answer your question on this site, the answer would be way too long for the Q&A format, and a blog post or official documentation pages are better suited for what you ask. I remember reading something about testing in one of the latest [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net/) newsletters, though ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two types of tests are supported, available in a drop-down menu in the `Build Variants` tool window of Android Studio:

1. [Android Instrumentation Tests](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html): integration/functional testing using a running app on a device or on an emulator, often referred to as Android Tests
2. [Unit Tests](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support): plain JUnit tests that run on a local JVM, with a stubbed android.jar provided

The [Testing Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) page mostly discusses Android Instrumentation Tests, with which, as you noted, is a bit tough to get started.

For your question, however, you just need Unit Tests.

From the [Unit testing support](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) page:

> 1. Update build.gradle to use the android gradle plugin version 1.1.0-rc1 or later (either manually in build.gradle file or in the UI in File > Project Structure)
> 2. Add necessary testing dependencies to app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

> 3. Enable the unit testing feature in Settings > Gradle > Experimental. (enabled and no longer experimental as of Android Studio 1.2)
> 4. Sync your project.
> 5. Open the "Build variants" tool window (on the left) and change the test artifact to "Unit tests".
> 6. Create a directory for your testing source code, i.e. src/test/java. You can do this from the command line or using the Project view in the Project tool window. The new directory should be highlighted in green at this point. Note: names of the test source directories are determined by the gradle plugin based on a convention.

Here is some sample code to test the instance method in your question (replace `com/domain/appname` with the path created by your package name):

**projectname/app/src/test/java/com/domain/appname/MyAdderTest.java**

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyAdderTest {
    private MyAdder mMyAdder;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Code that you wish to run before each test
        mMyAdder = new MyAdder();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Code that you wish to run after each test
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        final int sum = mMyAdder.add(3, 5);
        assertEquals(8, sum);        
    }
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful indeed I am now very close to test my application with your help so how do I run this test 

I understand we can Testcase X = new MyAdderTest("testAdd");
and I call X.run( ); 

So can you help me with where do I write this piece of code ???

Comment: can you also help me with mock testing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188828/android-unit-testing-with-junit-framework please have a look and answer

Comment: You can run the tests from the command line using `./gradlew test --continue` or in Android Studio by right-clicking on the test class and selecting "Run..."  Mocking is a huge topic, and you should consider first familiarizing yourself with [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html), then searching the web on mocking in Android.  Once you have concrete questions, open some new ones here on StackOverflow.