# Testing static methods in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have some experience with Android but I'm pretty new to testing. I've gone over the docs on the developer site and have read a some on tdd yet it feels like I'm missing some fundamentals on the thought process behind how to test code. I'm having trouble thinking about how to write a simple local unit tests for a specific case.

In short:What would be the best way to test something like a static method which uses the native JsonObject Class to parse some json.

eg. `Myclass.someStaticParsingFunction(jsonString);` //returns void

Would the dependency of this class to use the JsonObject library entail using something like Robo-electric or Espresso? Or is it possible to mock a JsonObject instance to test with. In that case, what would be the syntax for that?

Comment: Asking for resources/examples is off-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Testing in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168248/unit-testing-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to provide more detail and specify a use case.

Comment: if you need to test something with android dependencies you can run the test with roboelectric, the method is static, true but the method annotated with @Test won't be static